# how to do a sum in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a question about sql

I have a table 'Player' , what i want to archieve is to create a new table 'Level' from 'Player' , the nbPlayerPerLevel that i have done with simple sql as

```
select Level as LevelID,count(*) as nbPlayerPerLevel 
from Player
group by Level 
order by Level DESC
```

BUT what bother me is how could i get totalPlayer along with i did before, thanks a lot

Table:Player

```
 playerID  Level 
   1          3  
   2          5
   3          10
   4          3
   5          5 
---->
```

Table :Level

```
LevelID  nbPlayerPerLevel  totalPlayer
10             1              1
5              2              3
3              2              5
```

Comment: thanks @Raging Bull for the formating, that makes question more clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming totalPlayer is ment to be the number of players in a level equal to or higher than the given level, you need:

```
SELECT
  p.Level AS LevelID,
  IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT p.playerID),0) AS nbPlayerPerLevel,
  IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT pp.playerID),0) AS totalPlayer
FROM
  Player AS p
  LEFT JOIN Player AS pp ON p.Level<=pp.Level
GROUP BY p.Level 
ORDER BY p.Level DESC
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8a51/5/0)

Comment: Yep,it works, thanks a lot!! this is exactly the way that i was trying before but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.*, @TotPlayer := @TotPlayer + P.nbPlayerPerLevel as TotalPlayers 
FROM
(select Level as LevelID,count(*) as nbPlayerPerLevel
 from Player
 group by Level 
 order by Level DESC ) P,
(SELECT @TotPlayer := 0) T
```

Result:

```
LEVELID    NBPLAYERPERLEVEL  TOTALPLAYERS
10         1                 1
5          2                 3
3          2                 5
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8a51/47).

Comment: This works too, thanks a lot! I wish i could choose all your two answers!

Comment: @Summer_Solstice: No problem, my friend. Glad I could help.

Comment: Just a random crumb: While this needs no self-join, it depends on the levels being sorted top-to-bottom, so it is a bit fragile. No criticism, just the reasoning why I went with the boring but proven self-join.